# How to upgrade to the latest python 3.8 - 3.8.5 to 3.8.6 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, python, python3

Currently, when I do a latest apt update&upgrade (Ubuntu 20.04) I only end up with python 3.8.5 subversion of 3.8, although latest subversion of Python 3.8 is 3.8.6

I've looked at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python/ and it seems the package system just doesn't have the latest upgrade yet.

How would I upgrade to the latest python 3.8 (currently 3.8.6) without damaging future auto update?

Comment: Python3 in Ubuntu 20.04 is 3.8.2 (not 3.8.5). If it's upgraded at all, it may not be soon. The fundamental concept of an LTS release is that the software changes as little as possible for the whole five years. That means security patches and critical bugfixes only (with limited exceptions like web browsers, which are upgraded frequently for security reasons). For newer software, run a newer release of Ubuntu: 20.10 runs Python 3.8.6.

Comment: @user535733 The link I've provided states 3.8.5 and that link is listed here https://packages.ubuntu.com/ as `focal (20.04LTS)`, also I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and installed that python from the standard `apt` you are right about the newer Ubuntu release (groovy) - that one really has 3.8.6, but that seems a bit overkill to upgrade the whole OS.

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3. It's not overkill. The wrong version of Python3 will break your sytem quite horribly. It's a question of whether you want to use the LTS release *or* whether you want the newest software. Cannot stand still while running.

Comment: The logical solution would be to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.10. Sorry!

Comment: @user535733 sorry I think you missunderstood me, I understand why LTS has only certain versions - by overkill I meant upgrading OS just to get a new Python version, which I won't do since I want to keep the LTS.